# Node.js mock context.req.headers.referer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I implemented a redirect back to the previously visited page in a project and now have to adjust some tests which are failing because:

```
Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefine
```

I searched for some time but could not find a good solution or transfer the given answer to my current problem.

**Function**

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props> = async (ctx) => {
  ...

  const referer = ctx.req.headers.referer
  let backlink = referer

  if (!referer) {
  ...

    backlink = ...
  }

  return {
    props: {
      ...initialProps.props,
      product,
      backlink,
      ...
  }
}
```

**Test**

```
it('getServerSideProps should return product', async () => {
    mocked(getProductByKey).mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedProducts[0])
    const ctx = {
      query: { productKey: mockedProducts[0].key } as ParsedUrlQuery,
    }

    const result = await getServerSideProps(ctx as GetServerSidePropsContext)
    expect((result as any).props.product).toEqual(mockedProducts[0])
  })
```

Is there a way to mock the context.req.headers.referer? I would also need this for my own yet-to-be-written test for the redirect back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it just seems you have to add properties to your variable `ctx`.

The error is : `Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined`.

I can see `const referer = ctx.req.headers.referer` where `ctx.req` is undefined.

Two possibilities :

- First : it's a logic error, `req` or `req.headers` may be undefined sometimes, you should replace your javascript `const referer = ctx.req.headers.referer` by `const referer = ctx && ctx.req && ctx.req.headers && ctx.req.headers.referer` to add checks.
- Second : it's a test error, `req` and `req.headers` will always be defined and your mock is missing it. Just replace in your spec file :

```js
    const ctx = {
      query: { productKey: mockedProducts[0].key } as ParsedUrlQuery,
      req: { headers: {
        referer: 'backlink', // or undefined
      } }
    }
```

Your error should be fixed and you can edit the referer value (for the moment `'backlink'`) for other tests if needed.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented both of your suggestions.